# flask_smorest swagger-ui get parameter description

Tags: swagger, flask-smorest

I am using FLASK smores form my RESTapi application an have problem with documentation. I would like to have custom text in description field  with name of possible parameters an default one.

[Swagger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d75vj.png)

```
@ads_api.route('/test/<parameter>')
class test(MethodView):
   @ads_api.response(200, TestResponseSchema)
   def get(self,parameter):
       """ testing """
       print(parameter)
       if parameter in ['ex1','ex2', 'ex3']:
           response = {'status':'parameter exists'}
           return response
       else:
           abort(404, message='not found')
```

Response schema :

```
class TestResponseSchema(Schema):
    status = fields.Str(dump_only=True)
```

I could not find way to do that